# Awk multiline match, print output separated by newline

Tags: awk, multiline

I am following the example [How can I process multi-line records with awk in a bash script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/439732/how-can-i-process-multi-line-records-with-awk-in-a-bash-script)

My input is:

```
Restaurant: Chik-Fil-A 
City: Columbus
State: GA
Address: 123 Biscayne Blvd
Phone: 911

Restaurant: 5 guys
City: Columbus
State: GA
Address: 123 Peachtree Rd
Phone: 911

Restaurant: KFC
City: NYC
State: NY
Address: 123 Madison Square
Phone: 911

Restaurant: Bahama Breeze
City: Orlando
State: FL
Address: 123 Madison Square
Phone: 911
```

I want to select all restaurants in Columbus:

```
awk -v name="Columbus" -v RS="" '$0 ~ "City: " name' file.txt
```

My output is this:

```
Restaurant: Chik-Fil-A 
City: Columbus
State: GA
Address: 123 Biscayne Blvd
Phone: 911
Restaurant: 5 guys
City: Columbus
State: GA
Address: 123 Peachtree Rd
Phone: 911
```

What I would like is this:

```
Restaurant: Chik-Fil-A 
City: Columbus
State: GA
Address: 123 Biscayne Blvd
Phone: 911

Restaurant: 5 guys
City: Columbus
State: GA
Address: 123 Peachtree Rd
Phone: 911
```

I would like each output record to be separated by a newline. I've tried playing with FS and ORS but I keep on getting the same result. I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks,

Comment: How about `ORS=\n\n` ?

Comment: Awesome that works! Thanks! I had been trying ORS="\n". Out of interest, why do I need an additional NL?

Comment: The default `ORS` is a single newline, but since you want two you have to add another one

Comment: `$0 ~ "City: " name` will produce a false match if `name` is `London` and the town of `Londonderry` exists in the input file. You should use `$0 ~ ("(^|\n)City: " name "(\n|$)")` instead. And if you care about the possible `.` (or any other regexp metachars) in town names also creating false matches then add whatever variation of `BEGIN{ gsub(/[.]/,"[&]",name) }` makes sense to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `ORS` to two newlines to obtain the desired output:

```bash
awk -v name="Columbus" -v ORS="\n\n" -v RS="" '$0 ~ "City: " name' file.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples using `match` function with regex in it try following `awk` code.

```
awk -v name="Columbus" -v ORS="\n\n" -v RS="" '
match($0,"\nCity: " name"\n")
' Input_file
```

Comment: Nice use of the `'\n'` as a pseudo-anchor to address Ed's concerns.

Comment: I never knew that `RS=""` means paragraph mode, very clever match.

Answer (score 1):

A bit safer than `~` or `match`, especially if you may have characters in `name` that would be interpreted as regex operators (periods, stars, square brackets...):

```
awk -v name="Columbus" -v RS="" -v ORS='\n\n' '
  {c=$0; sub(/.*\nCity: */,"",c); sub(/\n.*/,"",c)} c==name' file.txt
```

(use `sub` to retain only the city name in `c` and compare for equality instead of regex match).

Note that if your city names cannot contain regex operators `grep` offers a simpler solution:

```
name=Columbus
grep "^City:[[:space:]]\+$name\$" -A4 -B1 file.txt
```